# DTOs in WCF RIA Services Master-Detail

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, dto, data-transfer-objects

I have to make a Master-Detail scenario where in the master I can show many types of items, that they all implement `IDto`:

```
interface IDto
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Title { get; set; }
  EntityType { get; set;
}

enum EntityType
{
  Contact,
  Person,
  Company,
  Customer
  Employee,
  Vendor,
  Job  
}
```

Note: I am using Entity Framework EDM (generated `ObjectContext` and `EntityObject`s).

The class hierarchy is that `Contact` is the subclass for `Person` and `Company`, `Person` is the baseclass of `Employee`, `Company` is the baseclass of `Vendor`. `Customer` has a property `Contact` that can be either a `Contact` or a `Person`, and has a list of `Job`.

[image]

Now in the master list, I want to load a collection of DTOs from the `DomainService` (it's a `LinqToEntitiesDomainService<ObjectContext>`, and I want only the specified fields in the `IDto` contract to be selected, then, when selected, load the entire entity with all its fields/related data etc. in the details area.

**Update**: I thought about another idea.
Create a database-view (SQL2008) that returns the 3 rows of the above `IDto` contract where the enum will be stored as int or tinyint (will then change the enum to byte), then in the edm I can make a table-per-hierarchy for each EntityType stored in the list, and return it from the `DomainService`.

BTW, all the enum values will be used for the query, in fact, no entity will return `Contact` for its `EntityType` property, because `Contact` is abstract and can be either a `Person` or a `Company`, but I still want to have an option to query both of them.

**Update 2**
The customer also wants, for each one of the items in the list, also all its jobs.
Based on the hierarchy I described above, for a `Customer` - select all its jobs; for a `Contact` or a `Person` - select its `Customer`'s `Job`s (if its a `Customer`). `Vendor` or `Employee`s are not meant to be register with `Job`s.

I think the only way I can do this is with database-views.
Am I wrong? What are the consequences? I am using SL5 with RIA.

Is the Views way good? Or I should handle all the queries in the client using a client POCO? because really this value are only used to retrieve the contact name and its jobs. further details and manipulation will be done in other views on the `Entity` entities them selves.

So what do you experts think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2653134) post very useful, and it actually let me to a desicion.

1. Database views is not necessarily the right approach
2. Will return the partial entities thru POCO DTOs from the domain service.